# Can you use controller as syntax with directive/ng-transclude?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm using `controller as` syntax. Inside this scope, I have a directive which transcludes content that access this controller. That controller appears to be inaccessible from within the ng-transclude.

DEMO: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZYPCym2WQV43wh4R4nwI?p=preview

Is there a restraint from using controller as from within transcluded content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think stuff is getting mixed up b/c of the way you're using `ng-controller` with a directive. Unfortunately, I can't explain why, but the way you were setting up the controller seemed funny to me :)

My thinking is, if you're putting `ng-controller` on an element that is a directive, you might as well make it a "directive controller" like this:

```
function transcludeDirective() {
  return {
      restrict: 'E',
      transclude:true,
      scope: false,
      controller: DemoCtrl,
      controllerAs: 'DemoCtrlVM',
      template: '<div>'+
                  '<p>First name: <b>{{ DemoCtrlVM.first_name }}</b></p>'+
                  '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>'+
                '</div>'
  }
}
```

Be sure to remove the `ng-controller="DemoCtrl as DemoCtrlVM"` from the HTML.  If you do this, it [works as expected](http://plnkr.co/edit/g5woylnnBhtvkRdPJZFH?p=preview).

This might not be what you want. Doing it your way, you could use a different controller with the directive, and doing it my way the controller is coupled to the directive...